# Trying to static compile a Qt Application using mingw32-make command but getting errors with #include statements

Tags: c++, qt, mingw32, static-compilation

I wrote a text editor application which I want to compile statically. I followed the instructions outlined on [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment-windows.html#linking-the-application-to-the-static-version-of-qt) page.

I went to the directory where all the source files were.
Ran:

```
1. mingw32-make clean //no problems
2. qmake -config release //no problems
and finally
3. mingw32-make
```

, and that's where I got a list of errors all caused by the #include statements in my code. Like, if I wrote `#include <QMainWindow>`, i'd get an error

> QMainWindow: no such file or directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you mean, did I write #include <QMainWindow.h>? Nope. I tried to see if it worked that way but no luck.

Comment: What's probably happening is that `qmake` reference the directory where the Qt headers reside, whereas with `mingw32-make` you would have to specify them explicitly

Comment: I believe you need to run `qmake` as the MOC is needed for classes containing the `Q_OBJECT` macro such as `QMainWindow` will have. Two phase compilation is one of the few downsides of Qt.

Comment: Wait, do you mean run qmake in step 2? I did that - sorry I made a mistake when I typed my steps. I've edited it now.

Comment: In that case it probably is failing to find your Qt directory. Are your environment variables set correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there a way I could check whether they're correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .pro try this line: "QT += gui"

Answer (score 1):

In MSVC2010 using `qmake` `nmake` I resolved this by replacing instances of

```
#include <QMainWindow>
```

with

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
```